# How to debug UTF-16 output in DbgView?

Tags: c++

I want to display a UTF-16 string in DbgView, like this:

```
wchar_t nameholder = L'שלום עולם';
```

But I can't do this with `OutputDebugStringW()`. Do you have any solution?

Comment: Check the [important](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-outputdebugstringw) note.  Waiting for DbgView to catch up isn't very practical.  Consider logging.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, this: `wchar_t nameholder = L'שלום עולם';` doesn't compile at all in any encoding.  You really meant:

```
const wchar_t* nameholder = L"שלום עולם";
```

In any case, the root of the real solution is in th same thing I said on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60367519/qt-dont-support-unicode-for-visual-studio-or-font-error/60367838#60367838).

Don't hardcode unicode characters (those above the normal ascii range) into a c++ source file.  Between compilers, ide editors, source code repos, diffing tools, and team members with a different setup, it's not a good idea to put unicode chars into a source code file.

So instead of this:

```
const wchar_t* nameholder = L"שלום עולם";
```

Use unicode escapes like this.

```
const wchar_t* nameholder = L"\u05e9\u05dc\u05d5\u05dd\u0020\u05e2\u05d5\u05dc\u05dd";
```

Then OutputDebugString will work better:

```
OutputDebugStringW(nameholder);
```

Disclaimer: I've never used Hebrew with DbgView, <strike>but it should work</strike>.  OutputDebugString with the above does work in Visual Studio:

```
'ConsoleApplication26.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'. 
The thread 0x2248 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
שלום עולם
```

**Update**

[image]

I tried Boris's suggestion and actually tried getting DbgView to run with my proposed changes.  And I tried both utf-16 with OutputDebugStringW and utf-8 with OutputDebugStringA.   Short answer: DbgView just mangles it.  So, pretty much everything I said is nearly moot.  I'll continue to stand by the fact that you should avoid non-ascii chars in source code.  But I don't have a solution for DbgView.

Comment: Putting the "hardcoding unicode characters in the source code" aside (i agree, its not a good idea), i've tried this on my Win7x64, with VS2017 to build the code and VS2017 or dbgview 4.79 on the receiving end, and i most definitely get every character outside my system locale substituted with '?'. Probably not going to investigate this any further (is it dbgview? VS? Win7 did they fix it in any newer version of the above?) but would be curious to read others results.

Comment: @BorisLipschitz - That's a good point about older versions of Windows.  It could be a font or control issue. Windows made huge improvements to unicode characters available in all fonts and rendered in all text controls in the last 10 years. Many of these improvements were made long after Windows 7 was was shipped.  In Windows 10, other than the console cmd window itself, rendering unicode chars is very reliable.

Comment: @BorisLipschitz - However, dbgview still manges the output regardless of whether I feed it utf16 with OutputDebugStringW or utf-8 via OutputDebugStringA.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the helping, so for the conclusion, i can't print utf16 in dbgview?
I don't really use hardcore hebrew in my project is only was for the example.

Comment: @yoni, it WILL print Hebrew in dbgview as long as the system locale is set to Hebrew, and it is, for most Israeli users, but hey, why bother? Those are intended to be DEBUG messages. Whats the point of having them in multiple languages? Or do you need an actual data printed for debug? Cause if thats the case, hey, just hex-dump it.

Comment: @yoni the bottom line here - (1) having unicode characters directly inside you source code, as text, is a bad idea, so printing traces in there in your native language is a bad idea as well... (2) unicode characres output is dependent on the receiving tool, that may mangle it (dbgview), system settings, possibly OS versions, making it an unreliable solution if you ever going to ask a user "record me a log in dbgview"... so, why do this?

Comment: @BorisLipschitz Hey, i just want print a player list from a game, and the names is in UTF-16 so there is name in hebrew, russian, and more, that's the reason i want to print it in dbgview, i must use dbgview.

Comment: i change my locale to hebrew, and i still don't see hebrew characters :( i see ascii things

Answer (score 0):

This made me curious, so i did a little experiment, building and running the following code on my Win7x64 machine with VS2017

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    static const wchar_t shalomolam[] = { 0x05E9, 0x05DC, 0x05D5, 0x05DD, 0x0020, 0x05E2, 0x05D5, 0x05DC, 0x05DD, 0xD, 0xA, 0 };
    static const wchar_t zdravstvuimir[] = { 0x0417, 0x0434, 0x0440, 0x0430, 0x0432, 0x0441, 0x0442, 0x0432, 0x0443, 0x0439, 0x0020, 0x041C, 0x0438, 0x0440, 0xD, 0xA, 0 };
    OutputDebugStringW(L"Hello World\r\n");
    OutputDebugStringW(shalomolam);
    OutputDebugStringW(zdravstvuimir);
    return(0);
}
```

Surprisingly, I've only got either English or system locale Unicode characters to print, having my system set to Hebrew locale the Hebrew would print, but the Russian characters are converted to '?', setting it to Russian and the same happens to Hebrew. Knowing it may have to do with the source file encoding, Visual Studio, etc (i agree with @selbie on this), i've double checked the binary with a hex editor, the strings are there, and they are fine, and it doesn't depend on what system locale i've run the build. This '?' substitution happens in both dbgview and Visual Studio debug output.

TBH, i've never even attempted to feed non-English Unicode characters to OutputDebugString until now, but hey, i guess your answer is - if you want a specific languages output for debug purposes - switch your locale to that language. Otherwise (such as, in case of multiple languages, or if you want to collect a log with dbgview on a user's machine) guess you are out of luck.

Comment: The success of the above depends on what encoding you saved the source file. Try saving your source file as UTF-16.  See my answer as well.

Comment: @selbie read mine again as well. I know. And i agree with your answer. Thats why i've double checked in the binary, with a hex editor, just in case.

Comment: @selbie - you know what... just to be on the safe side... i've just ran it with raw data for Hebrew and Russian, and i still only get Hebrew (well, and English) printed right when my system locale is set to Hebrew. Editing the answer for the code with raw data.