# C++ unicodes in array

Tags: c++, unicode

Currently, I'm trying to put unicode characters in an array. It doesn't seem that Visual Studio Code 2019 is good with this.

```
std::string numbers[9] = { "едно", "двe", "три", "четири", "пет", "шест", "седем", "осем", "девет" };
```

I've tried to activate the unicode with the chcp  in the console, but it seems like it's not just the console, but the values in the array.

I'll be grateful if someone has any ideas.

Comment: You need to align your file encoding with the encoding your compiler expects. If you then want to do something useful with these strings (ie printing) you should _also_ make sure your output is set up for that encoding. Best to stick to UTF-8 for all three.

Comment: `std::string` works witch `char`, which is an 8-bit type. `std::wstring` works with `wchar_t` and is probably what you need. But then you have to use `L` as in `L"едно"`

Comment: In 2020, use `u8"едно"` for UTF-8 string literals. And then make sure the terminal on your operating system supports Unicode characters. Linux usually does by default. You might need to turn it on manually in Windows.

Comment: Or you can use `std::u16string` or `std::u32string` and `u"едно"` or `U"едно"`. Lot's of options but you have to understand what you are asking for.

Comment: I've answered this before.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60367838/104458) is an answer I gave to a recent variation of this same question.  While you can save the source file as UTF-8 (which should solve your issue), text file encodings are rather volatile between source control systems.